# Calculate price of 1 UNI-V2-LP tokens

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Calculating the price of 1 token can be done by

`1 token in wei = _reserve0 / _reserve1`

But how would I calculate the price of 1 UNI-V2-LP token?

Naively - I think that it's 50/50 tokens/weth, so if we know what 1 token is, we can multiply it by 2, but since that ratio changes, but I'm not confident that's right.

```
eth price: 2200.00
eth reserves: 0.119356234964025982
token price 0.000000000000718151
token reserves: 390342304817971.397725688376686955
UNI-V2 total supply: 6785955.522838924121357138
1 token = 0.119356234964025982 / 390342304817971.397725688376686955 == 0.000000000000000305
```

Comment: `Naively - I think that it's 50/50 tokens/weth, so if we know what 1 token is, we can multiply it by 2, but since that ratio changes, but I'm not confident that's right.` This is correct